# changing data type for a field in protocol buffer

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

Hi is it Okay to change the data type of a field in protocol buffer, in order to maintain backward compatibility. for example

**Old message:**

```
message Connection{
       optional string wifi = 1;
       optional int32 wifiCode = 2;
}
```

**New message:**

```
message Connection{
     message wifiConnection{
         optional string name = 1;
         optional int32 code = 2;
     }

     optional wifiConnection wifi = 1;
}
```

So basically I have not changed the tag number for the field nor renamed it, but I have changed the data type. So would this be backward compatible ? If a get an old proto object created with previous schema, can it be parsed through object created by this new schema ?

Comment: It doesn't look like it would be backward compatible.

Answer (score 3):

**No it would not be backward compatible**. Protcol Buffers stores data roughly like

```
Code1 + wire-type1 + {Data1}
Code2 + wire-type2 + {Data2}
Code3 + wire-type3 + {Data3}
```

So the first old format would be stored like

```
1 + wire-type {Wifi-Data}
2 + wire-type {Wifi-Code-Data}
```

The new message would be stored like

```
1 + wire-type { 
               1 + wire-type {Wifi-Data}
               2 + wire-type {Wifi-Code-Data}
}
```